# Upgarding opencart from 1.5.6.4 to 2.x.x. Giving JSON error

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I am trying to upgrade my opencart system from 1.5.x to 2.x.x I have taken backup of the old database. Then I have copied all the files from new version to the version I have installed(Old Version). Then I go to the screen http://localhost/abc/install. A ugrade screen appears infront of me. When I click on upgrade it starts upgrading the system. But after some time it came out with a JSON error.

Can any one tell me where I am going wrong in upgrading the system. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the place to get the actual support of your websites. You can describe what you have tried so far and what is the error you got when upgraded. Upgrading opencart is not easy task until you have experience with opencart. I would recommend hiring a developer for this task and have a safe upgrade 
This is the link to developer that might be useful for you
http://templatecinderella.com/opencart-upgrade-service.html or email to vedibadiyan@gmail.com